# How to retrieve data from session and save the value to database

Tags: php, laravel, session, eloquent

i'm new in laravel. i make some register form in different page. In each page form, i save the input to session and so on. After last page, I want all data in session save in table at database. But, i don't understand how session work. I need someone give me advice how to use session and what i had to do is right or wrong.  this is my **Controller** for **Register**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Session;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
| validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
| provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
|
*/

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
protected function show(){
    return view('auth.register');
}

protected function save(Request $request){
    if(Session::has('SaveRegister')){

    $value = \Request::all();

    $temporarydata = Session::push('SaveRegister',$value);


    }
    else

    {
        $data = \Request::all();  
        Session::put('SaveRegister',[]);
        Session::put('SaveRegister', $data);
    }

}

protected function showform(){

    return view('auth.registertwo');
    //return view('auth.registerv');
}
protected function showformfinal(){
    //$print = Session::get('SaveRegister');
    return view('auth.final');
    //return view('auth.registerv');
}

protected function showformverification(){
    return view('auth.verify');
}

 }
```

this is my first form register

```
@include('layouts.header')
```

```
        <div class="row clearfix mb mt">
            <div class="breadcrumbIn">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="toptip" title="Homepage"> <i class="icon-home"></i> </a></li>
                    <li style="color:#000;"> Register </li>
                    <li style="color:#000;"> Step One </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- breadcrumb -->
        </div><!-- row -->

        <div class="row row-fluid clearfix mbf">
            <div class="def-block clearfix">
                <h4 style="color:#fff;"> Artist Sign Up </h4><span class="liner"></span>



                <div class="grid_12 mt">
                    <form method="post" id="contactForm" action="{{ url('/register/session') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <div class="clearfix">
                        <label for="NameLabel" style="color:#fff;">Name</label>
                            <div class="grid_12"><input type="text" name="senderName" id="senderName" placeholder="Please input your band name" class="requiredField"/></div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                        <label for="EmailLabel" style="color:#fff;">Email</label>
                        <div class="grid_12"><input type="text" name="senderEmail" id="senderEmail" placeholder="Please input your email address" class="requiredField email"/></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                        <label for="UsernameLabel"style="color:#fff;">Username</label>
                        <div class="grid_12"><input type="text" name="senderUsername" id="senderEmail" placeholder="Please input your email address" class="requiredField"/></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                        <label for="PasswordLabel" style="color:#fff;">Password</label>
                        <div class="grid_12"><input type="password" name="senderPassword" id="senderEmail" placeholder="Please type your password" class="requiredField"/></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                        <label for="PasswordLabel" style="color:#fff;">Confirm Password</label>
                        <div class="grid_12"><input type="password" name="senderCPassword" id="senderEmail" placeholder="Please type your password" class="requiredField"/></div>
                        </div>


                        <input type="submit" id="sendMessage" name="sendMessage" value="Next >" />
                        <span>  </span>
                    </form><!-- end form -->
                </div><!-- end grid6 -->

            </div><!-- def block -->

        </div><!-- row clearfix -->
    </div><!-- end page content -->
```

this is my second form at different page

```
@include('layouts.header')
```

```
        <div class="row clearfix mb mt">
            <div class="breadcrumbIn">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="toptip" title="Homepage"> <i class="icon-home"></i> </a></li>
                    <li style="color:#000;"> Register</li>
                    <li style="color:#000;"> Step One</li>
                    <li style="color:#000;"> Step Two</li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- breadcrumb -->
        </div><!-- row -->

        <div class="row row-fluid clearfix mbf">
            <div class="def-block clearfix">
                <h4 style="color:#fff;"> Artist Sign Up </h4><span class="liner"></span>



                <div class="grid_12 mt">
                    <form method="post" id="RegisterForm" action="{{ url('/register/session') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <div class="clearfix">
                        <label for="NameLabel" style="color:#fff;">City</label>
                            <div class="grid_12"><input type="text" name="senderCity" id="senderName" placeholder="Please input your city" class="requiredField"/></div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                        <label for="EmailLabel" style="color:#fff;">Formed Date</label>
                        <div class="grid_12"><input type="date" name="senderFormedDate" id="senderEmail" class="requiredField"/></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                        <label for="UsernameLabel"style="color:#fff;">Genre</label>
                        <div class="grid_12"><input type="text" name="senderGenre" id="senderEmail" placeholder="Please input your band's genre" class="requiredField"/></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                        <label for="PasswordLabel" style="color:#fff;">Website</label>
                        <div class="grid_12"><input type="text" name="senderWebsite" id="senderEmail" placeholder="Please input your band's website"/></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                        <label for="PasswordLabel" style="color:#fff;">Contact</label>
                        <div class="grid_12"><input type="text" name="senderContact" id="senderEmail" placeholder="Please input your band's contact person" class="requiredField"/></div>
                        </div>


                        <input type="submit" id="sendMessage" name="sendMessage" value="Next >" />
                        <span>  </span>
                    </form><!-- end form -->
                </div><!-- end grid6 -->

            </div><!-- def block -->

        </div><!-- row clearfix -->
    </div><!-- end page content -->
```

and this is my third form page

```
@include('layouts.header')
```

```
        <div class="row clearfix mb mt">
            <div class="breadcrumbIn">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="toptip" title="Homepage"> <i class="icon-home"></i> </a></li>
                    <li style="color:#000;">Register</li>
                    <li style="color:#000;">Step One</li>
                    <li style="color:#000;">Step Two</li>
                    <li style="color:#000;">Step Three</li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- breadcrumb -->
        </div><!-- row -->

        <div class="row row-fluid clearfix mbf">
            <div class="def-block clearfix">
                <h4 style="color:#fff;"> Artist Sign Up </h4><span class="liner"></span>



                <div class="grid_12 mt">
                    <form method="post" id="FinalForm" action="{{ url('/register/session') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <div class="clearfix">
                        <label for="NameLabel" style="color:#fff;font-size:16px;">Sounds like</label>
                            <div class="grid_12"><textarea rows="16"  placeholder="Describe your bands soundslike" class="requiredField" ></textarea></div>
                        </div>


                        <input type="submit" id="sendMessage" name="sendMessage" value="Next >" />
                        <span>  </span>
                    </form><!-- end form -->
                </div><!-- end grid6 -->

            </div><!-- def block -->

        </div><!-- row clearfix -->
    </div><!-- end page content -->
```

and this is my last page(upload a file)

```
@include('layouts.header')
```

```
        <div class="row clearfix mb mt">
            <div class="breadcrumbIn">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="toptip" title="Homepage"> <i class="icon-home"></i> </a></li>
                    <li style="color:#000;"> Register </li>
                    <li style="color:#000;"> Step One </li>
                    <li style="color:#000;"> Step Two </li>
                    <li style="color:#000;"> Step Three </li>
                    <li style="color:#000;"> Final Step </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- breadcrumb -->
        </div><!-- row -->

        <div class="row row-fluid clearfix mbf">
            <div class="def-block clearfix">
                <h4 style="color:#fff;"> Artist Sign Up </h4><span class="liner"></span>



                <div class="grid_12 mt">
                    <form method="post" id="contactForm" action="{{ url('/register/session') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <div class="clearfix">
                        <label for="NameLabel" style="color:#fff;">Press Release(please upload file with .pdf format)</label>
                            <div class="grid_12"><input type="file" name="senderName" id="senderName" placeholder="Please input your band name" class="requiredField"/></div>
                            </div>


                        <input type="submit" id="sendMessage" name="sendMessage" value="Next >" />
                        <span>  </span>
                    </form><!-- end form -->
                </div><!-- end grid6 -->

            </div><!-- def block -->

        </div><!-- row clearfix -->
    </div><!-- end page content -->
```

and this is my route

```
<?php


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
 });

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/news', 'NewsController@index');

Route::group(['prefix'=>'register'], function(){
Route::get('/v1','Auth\RegisterController@show');
Route::post('/session','Auth\RegisterController@save');
Route::get('/steptwo','Auth\RegisterController@showform');
Route::get('/stepthree','Auth\RegisterController@showformfinal');
Route::get('/tes', function(){
    return view('blank');
});
Route::get('/verification','Auth\RegisterController@showformverification');
});
```

Comment: [How to retrieve session data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#retrieving-data)

Comment: Could you share some sample code on how the form looks, and how each form page is currently saved to the session?

Comment: i was add the code above @Quezler

Comment: Could you share the code of `Auth\RegisterController@save`? how to retrieve from the session will depend on how it can be saved to the database

Comment: i had add the code above. `Auth\RegisterController@save` is in register controller at protected function save{}. @Quezler

Comment: Then on your final registration page it should be `Session::get('SaveRegister')` if i am not mistaken

Comment: Javascript is your friend here... why do you go to the server each time?

Comment: is it possible to save session through javascript?